# Index out of range error when selecting any row other than 1st

Tags: indexing, range, out

I'm getting the "Index out of range error", when double clicking the datagridview any row other than 1st. Double clicking 1st row gives the value. Please help

My code as follows:

```
    Private Sub dgv_searchassistant_CellDoubleClick(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles dgv_searchassistant.CellDoubleClick

    Dim rowindex As Integer = dgv_searchassistant.CurrentCell.RowIndex
    Dim columnindex As Integer = dgv_searchassistant.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex

    TextBox30.Text = dgv_searchassistant.Rows(rowindex).Cells(columnindex).Value
    TextBox27.Text = dgv_searchassistant.Rows(rowindex).Cells(2).Value

    dgv_searchassistant.Visible = False
    dgv_searchassistant.AutoGenerateColumns = False
    dgv_searchassistant.DataSource = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Does the row at `rowindex` have 3 cells?

Comment: Yes it has 7 columns. This is the statement for populating the columns : Select  invreg_supplier as 'Supplier', invreg_invnum as 'Invoice #', invreg_ipapprovalnum as 'Approval #',invreg_ipapprovaldate as 'Approval date',invreg_mohactual as 'Actual MOH fees paid' ,invreg_mohvouchernum as 'MOH voucher #',  invreg_ippaystatusfull as 'IP payment status' from Invoiceregister where invreg_mohvouchernum Like  '%" & searchstring & "%' and invreg_ipapprovalstatus = 'Approved for import' order by invreg_mohvouchernum"

Comment: waiting for a helping hand...

Comment: Got the answer ... Posting the link if someone requires.... https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/15a3adbe-5483-41ad-8f77-7aade958b5af/index-out-of-range-error-when-selecting-any-row-other-than-1st?forum=vbgeneral#15a3adbe-5483-41ad-8f77-7aade958b5af